# Django Priority Queue

Tags: django, django-models, django-middleware

I want to build a delivery app in Django, wherein I will create delivery objects to be delivered according to priority(attribute of the object) by a delivery person. I will login and create the tasks and there can be many delivery persons to login and accept task asynchronously. 
Objects(tasks) will be popped out as a delivery person logs in and accepts the task, and the next logged in delivery person would see the next priority task.

How can this be implemented in Django? Any references and implementation links are welcomed. Thanks in advance!